# iOS application development

Tags: android, ios, web

I work for a project where we are working on web application, android and iOS applications. We are developing the web application on Linux.

I would like to know if:

1. Android applications can be developed on Linux using Android SDK?
2. iOS applications can be developed without using a Mac, using Objective-C?
3. Is there a way to build one application and use it across multiple smartphone OS platforms?

Currently, I am working on the web application. Once this is done, I am planning on mobile application development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Yes...You can use Linux (along with other OS's) to develop an Android application.
2. I'm not too sure, maybe others can go deeper into this.  I know you can develop Apps using 
   Windows but i'm not sure how deep that goes.  I think you can go as far as debugging it but i don't think you can test it (on sim) and of course you need Xcode to submit your app to the app store.
3. Yes, you can use platforms such as [phone gap](http://phonegap.com) to develop cross platform apps using web technologies such as HTML, CSS and JS. I've never used phone gap (or similar technologies) but many people seem to like it.  Of course, if you choose to build apps that are not native (i.e. using phone gap), performance levels are expectedly lower than their native counterparts.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly develop Android applications on a whole host of OS platforms.
It's at best an uphill fight to build iOS applications without a Mac, possibly worse. Apple expects you to use XCode on MacOS.
There are a couple of "cross mobile OS" products out there, notably Ximarin and Apportable. I can't vouch for either and both are likely to have some trade-offs for and against. (Anyone here using Apportable yet?)

Comment: Apportable is mostly for porting iOS apps to Android, it requires a Mac and Xcode.

Comment: Which means Apportable would imply NO on 2 but YES on 3, still potentially interesting, if it works well.